# How must we declare a struct?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct cellule
{
    int numero;
    int poids;
    struct cellule *suivant;
}Celulle, *LISTE;  



LISTE graphe[TAILLE];
```

I do not understand what is the meaning of `*LISTE`?

Comment: Its someone's attempt at being helpful by hiding a pointer-to-struct type in a typedef alias. It's also a *terrible* practice for C programmers because it actually makes the code *harder* to manage, not easier. There are only two scenarios where pointer aliasing in typedefs is warranted (blackbox handle APIs and callback function specifications), and this is *neither*.

Comment: Do you know `typedef` in general? `typedef struct cellule { ... } *LISTE;` is equivalent to `struct cellule { ... }; typedef struct cellule *LISTE;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 acceptable ways to declare this struct:

```
typedef struct cellule
{
    int numero;
    int poids;
    struct cellule *suivant;
}Celulle;

// usage:
Celulle c;
```

or

```
struct cellule
{
    int numero;
    int poids;
    struct cellule *suivant;
};

// usage:
struct celulle c;
```

Which one to pick is a matter of coding style. The former is by far most common. The latter is used in Linux style programs. Either is fine.

What is never ok however, is to hide a pointer behind a `typedef`. Your originally code does this, defining a type `LISTE` which is actually a `Celulle*` pointer. Hiding pointers like this create confusion and is known to cause bugs because of it. Your original program should instead be rewritten to something like this:

```
typedef struct cellule
{
    int numero;
    int poids;
    struct cellule* suivant;
}Celulle;

Celulle* graphe[TAILLE];
```

Answer (score 3):

There is already a lot of info about this.

Basically is an alias to a pointer to the struct you defined.

```
typedef struct cellule
{
    int numero;
    int poids;
    struct cellule *suivant;
}Celulle, *LISTE;
```

could be split in:

```
struct cellule
{
    int numero;
    int poids;
    struct cellule *suivant;
};

typedef struct cellule Celulle;
typedef struct cellule * LISTE;
```

Making LISTE an alias of a poniter to that struct.

`*Celulle` and `LISTE` are the same types.

```
LISTE graphe[TAILLE];
```

you are declaring an array of pointers (size TAILLE) to the struct.